# confusion in the definition of Euler class

Tags: algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes

I encountered an apparant contradiction while dealing with Euler classes and cannot seem to resolve this issue myself. I feel pretty silly but I need help. Here's the question:

Consider an oriented, real, $n$-dimensional vector bundle $\xi:E\to B$, and let $t\in H^n(E,E\setminus E_0)$ be the Thom class. Here $E_0$ is the image of the zero section $s:B\to E$. If $i:E\to (E,E\setminus E_0)$ denotes the inclusion, then by definition the Euler class $e(\xi )\in H^n(B)$ of $\xi$ is given by $$e(\xi)=s^*i^*t.$$
Now suppose that $\xi$ has an orientation-reversing automorphism, say $\Phi:E\to E.$ Then $\Phi ^*t=-t$, so $$-e(\xi)=s^*i^*\Phi^*t=s^*\Phi^*i^*t=s^*i^*t=e(\xi),$$ whence  $2e(\xi)=0$. But the tangent bundle $TS^2=\{(p,v,w)\in S^2\times \mathbb{R}^3\mid\langle v,w\rangle=0\}$ of $S^2$ admits an orientation-reversing automorphism $(p,v,w)\mapsto (p,w,v)$, and its Euler class, which is twice a generator of $H^2(S^2)\cong \mathbb{Z}$, isn't even a torsion! **Where did I make a mistake?**

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Um, $TS^2 = \{(p,v)\in S^2\times\Bbb R^3: \langle p,v\rangle = 0\}$.

Comment: @TedShifrin You're right. Thanks for pointing that out. (I feel very, very stupid...) Is the proof that $2e(\xi)=0$ fine?

Comment: No. There can be no orientation-reversing automorphism, as your argument indeed shows.

Comment: @Ted Sorry for not being clear. My question is: "My argument shows that if an oriented vector bundle of rank $n$, which has nothing to do with spheres, admits an orientation-reversing automorphism, then its Euler class $e$ satisfies $2e=0$. Is this argument correct?"

Comment: Ah, yes, that seemed fine to me. From the differential geometry viewpoint, integrating the Pfaffian of curvature should give $0$, which says indeed that the Euler class is torsion.

Comment: @Ted Hah, I'm afraid I don't know enough differential geometry to understand your comment, but thank you nonetheless. I really appreciate your help and perseverance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Ted Shifrin, the definition of the tangent bundle of $S^2$ in the question is (blatantly) wrong...